# Promise JavaScript Returning Empty Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

`createFolder()` function is returning an empty array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but it needs to return the items within `project_array`

```
function get_project_folders(){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    fs.readdir(__dirname + '/projects', (error, data1)=>{
      if(error){
        reject(console.log(`Error. Unable to read directory - ${error}`))
      }else{
        resolve(data1)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```
async function createFolder(){
  let list_of_projects = await get_project_folders()
  let project_array = []


  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    for(let project of list_of_projects){
      let splitProject = project.split("-")
      fs.readdir(__dirname + `/projects/${splitProject[0]}-${splitProject[1]}`, (error, data1)=>{
        if(error){
          console.log('Error. Unable to read directory.')
        }else{
          project_array.push({circuit: splitProject[0], fuse: splitProject[1], pole: data1})
        }
      })
    }
    resolve(project_array)
  })
}
```

```
async function testIt(){
  let folderData = await createFolder()
  console.log(folderData)
}

testIt()
```

Comment: Have you seen what `get_project_folders` returns?

Comment: Yes it returns the folder names as desired. Create folder function is the only function that is not returning the data that I need

Comment: This is an async issue - your last resolve happens before your fs calls have resolved. You should do something like `await Promise.all( list_of_projects.map(...) )` and then resolve your wrapping Promise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic, what you are doing is resolving the promise with the empty array before your node fs async methods have resolved. Try this instead:

```js
async function createFolder(){

  const list_of_projects = await get_project_folders();
  const result = await Promise.all( list_of_projects.map(project => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const splitProject = project.split("-");
    fs.readdir(__dirname + `/projects/${splitProject[0]}-${splitProject[1]}`, (error, data1) => {
      if(error){
        console.error('Error. Unable to read directory.');
        resolve( null );
      } else {
        resolve({
          circuit: splitProject[0],
          fuse: splitProject[1],
          pole: data1
        });
      }
    });
  });
  
  // Filter out the errors that resolved as `null`
  return result.filter( Boolean );
  
}
```

In essence, wrap every `fs.` call in a promise, then use `Promise.all` to generate an array of promises. Because `Promise.all` requires all to be resolved for it to be resolved, make sure you even resolve when there is an error - just return something falsy (in my case `null`) so you can filter it out later.

Comment: An alternative to wrapping everything yourself would be to `const {promises: {readdir}} = require('fs')` or the same, but written out longer: `const fs2 = require('fs'); const readdir = fs2.readdir;` (using `import` is possible too, of course) & then use just use `await readdir(path)`.  Most Node.js internal libraries have an 'official' promise-based variant.

Comment: Sure, but without knowing the node version that might cause issues at the moment. By which I mean I love the syntax, but it isn’t standard in nodejs yet :(

Comment: `fs.promises` was stable in Node 10, so using it has been safe for a long while now. No need to be afraid of it anymore. :-)